# SDL Tridion Content Porter 2009 SP1 - Synchronize Content

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am having a problem Content Porting items between our SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 Development and (brand new and empty) Test environments and would like some clarification of functionality provided by Content Porter (2009 SP1) please...

I am doing an port of some 'Image' Multimedia Components.  However, these Image Components were created before the Schema was changed (in the Development environment) to remove a couple of fields ('height' and 'width').

These Components, along with the Schema, exported correctly with no errors.  However, when I am doing the import I am getting an error saying that the fields are missing from the Schema.  (Please see the error details below.)

I have tried checking the "Synchronize content against Schema before importing" option on the import settings, but despite the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP2/7DGH253HDJDJ884JJLLAPWWRSFDH3737388D4) saying "If the item has fields that are not present in the Schema, Content Porter removes them", I am still getting the same error.  Does this not work with Metadata fields or Multimedia Components, or am I missing something?

Thanks,
Jonathan

---

ERROR DETAILS:
[Error]

XML validation error. Reason: The element 'Metadata' in namespace 'uuid:0c8ff632-92a3-44f5-9253-a1a961155540' **has invalid child element 'height' in namespace 'uuid:0c8ff632-92a3-44f5-9253-a1a961155540**'. List of possible elements expected: 'alt_text' in namespace 'uuid:0c8ff632-92a3-44f5-9253-a1a961155540'..The element 'Metadata' in namespace 'uuid:0c8ff632-92a3-44f5-9253-a1a961155540' has invalid child element 'height' in namespace 'uuid:0c8ff632-92a3-44f5-9253-a1a961155540'. List of possible elements expected: 'alt_text' in namespace 'uuid:0c8ff632-92a3-44f5-9253-a1a961155540'

Comment: As an update on this, it appears that this problem is also present if a metadata field is removed from the schema of normal (not multimedia) component.  It appears that the "Synchronize content against Schema before importing" option does not cover metadata fields!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your best option is to ensure your Components are valid against their Schema before doing the export. So **either**:

1. manually Open and Save each relevant Component, in which case the Content Manager Explorer (the normal Web GUI) will fix your content **or**
2. run the Component Synchronizer from either the pre-2011 PowerTools  or the new ones that are being built (by volunteers from the community) as we speak.

Someone more familiar with may chime in on the actual cause, but until then these seem your quickest way forward.

Comment: Hi Frank.  I was saddened to hear that the Component Synchronizer will not make it in to the Powertools release at the end of the month.  I think that might be my call to get involved in the Powertools (with testing)!  I'm just going to create a simple custom page that opens and saves each component (based on Schema, Folder and date modified maybe). thanks,

Comment: That's great news - both on joining the PowerTools and on the temporary workaround - John. We'll see you "on the other side" and definitely reach out on either the Google Group or on the Flowdock if you need some help/guidance.